# Symfony form EntityType checkbox selected

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox, symfony-forms

On rendering a form how to we get checkboxes that are true in the database to be checked?

I can set a checkbox using choice_attr, but I can't find a way of checking if the particular checkbox should be checked.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)


'choice_attr' => function ($UserRoles, $key, $index) {
    return ($key == 1) ? ['checked' => true] : ['checked' => false];
},
```

Comment: If you add the fields with the formbuilder using your entity as the `data_class` for the defaults, this happens without having to do anything. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes for more information.

Comment: Thanks @DirkJ.Faber I am using data_class for the User Entity, but that doesn't help with the linked UserRoles Entity. I've worked out the solution and posted it below.

Comment: I guess you need custom form theme for that https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html

Comment: @MaxLipsky I am using bootstrap_5_layout.html.twig, but that is for style, not functionality. I've answered the question below using `'choice_attr' => function ($roles, $key, $index) use ($UserRoles)`

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was actually a simple one, I just didn't know about 'use' on a closure to inject the roles the user has.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $UserRoles = $options['data']->getRoles();

    ...

    $builder->add('roles', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => \App\Entity\UserRoles::class,

        'choice_label' => 'role',

        'choice_attr' => function ($roles, $key, $index) use ($UserRoles) {
            $selected = false;
            if(in_array($roles->getRole(), $UserRoles)) {
                $selected = true;
            }
            return ['checked' => $selected];
        },

        // used to render a select box, check boxes or radios
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'data' => null
    ])
}
```

Comment: There is something about this that doesn't seem right. If you simply want to show which roles (that are entities) a user has, you can use:
            `->add('roles', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'User roles(s)',
                'class' => Roles::class,
                'multiple' => true,
            ])`

Comment: You have removed the logic that checks the checkboxes that the user has. I think you're missing the point that the UserRoles entity holds all the roles available in the application. I don't just want to display which roles a user has. The above is working as intended.